# jekyll pages work locally but not when online

Tags: html, http-status-code-404, yaml, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to add a couple links to my jekyll page. Here is the code I added to my _data/links.yml file (Home was there previously, I added the last two):

```
- url: /
  title: Home

- url: /about
  title: About

- url: /thoughts
  title: Thoughts
```

It works locally but not when I host my page on github pages.  I know jekyll versions are different, I have 2.0.3 locally and I'm not sure what version is on github pages. But this seems like a relatively simple thing. When I click on these links I get a 404 error.

My page is here [int-A.github.io](http://int-A.github.io) and code is hosted [here](https://github.com/int-A). Is there something that changed in version 2 of Jekyll that would allow this to work but not on an older version (which ever is on github pages)

Comment: Could http://stackoverflow.com/a/14661141/6309 help?

Comment: Looks like your site is working great! Seems you've fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is something wrong with permalinks and baseurl="" combination.

Your pages do render at these locations:
http://int-a.github.io/thoughts/thoughts/
http://int-a.github.io/about/about/

I believe the solution would be to set the baseurl as `http://int-a.github.io` and permalink to `/index.html` instead of `/foldername/index.html`